# How to insert a body with a link through Gmail URL

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

How to open a window with a new Gmail email that has the following body

> Hi, here is the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org).

In other words, I am looking for an URL with the format

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm?body=<BODY>"
```

What is the proper `<BODY>` to represent the previously shown email body?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not pretty sure of what is intended. Something like this works:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&body=This+is+a+test`